# Zeroes of Laguerre polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, laguerre

The simplest Laguerre polynomials are 
$$
L_k(x)=(\frac{d}{dx}-1)^k\left(\frac{x^k}{k!}\right).
$$
I would like to find a simple reference for proving or disproving the following assertions.

(1) All the $k$ zeroes of $L_k$ are simple and located on the positive half-line.

(2) The largest zero of $L_k$ is bounded above by $k^2$.

Comment: (1) is granted, just because they are orthogonal polynomials on that domain.

Answer (score 3):

Both assertions hold true, in fact the roots lie in the interval 
$$(0,k+(k-1)\sqrt{k}).$$

There are many books for references, one among which is

"Basic Hypergeometric Series", by George Gasper, Mizan Rahman, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its applications.

Answer (score 1):

hmm derivatives interlace zeros... however $ a^+=1- d/dx$ behaves nicely on polynomials.  It should preserve positivity of the roots and shift the leading zero by $+n$ with a small correction term where $n = \deg p$.  here we have $x=0$ as a root with multiplicity $k$ and they should hop forward a bit